# Error en android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener, "Attempt to invoke virtual method"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Por que tengo en siguiente error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method ... on a null object reference

el signIn.java es

```
    public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtPhone,edtPassword;
    Button btnSignIn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        edtPassword = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        edtPhone = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
        btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);

        //init firebase

        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("Usuario");

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
                mDialog.setMessage("Por favor espera...");
                mDialog.show();


                table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {





                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        //comprobar si el usuario no existe en la base de datos
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).exists()) {

                            //Informacion usuario

                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Usuario usuario = dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(Usuario.class);
                            if (usuario.getContraseña().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Inicio de Sesión Exitoso !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Inicio de Sesión Fallido !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Usuario no registrado en base de dato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

El Codigo xml boton

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSignIn1"
    android:text="@string/SignIn"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonstyle1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="460dp"

    />
```

Gracias!!.

Comment: Neil, te recomiendo trata de agregar texto en lugar de imagenes del código, esto te ayudara a tener mejor aceptaciòn en tus preguntas, un saludo!

Comment: gracias lo haré c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al tratar de obtener la referencia del boton, no existe, por lo tanto `btnSignIn` tiene valor null

```
btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
```

Si el boton tiene un valor null, no puedes llamar un método, por esta razón obtienes el error.

> Attempt to invoke virtual method ... on a null object reference

Debes revisar que el boton con id `btnSignIn` en realidad se encuentre en el layout que carga tu activity que es: `activity_sign_in.xml`, si el botón se encuentra en el layout, asegura que su id sea correcto.

Comment: acabo de colocar el xml del boton pero la id esta bien al parecer

Comment: Neil, debe ser android:id="@+id/btnSignIn" y no android:id="@+id/btnSignIn1" , corrige el id y funcionará correctamente.

Comment: jajaja muchas gracias, no me di cuenta .

Comment: El problema que indica el Log es que tratas de llamar un método en una instancia con valor null.

Comment: si ya corre la aplicación gracias!!!

Comment: @Neil recuerda dar las gracias de manera constructiva, como marcando la respuesta como **Aceptada✅**, tal como se explica en el **[recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** del sitio.

Comment: verdad gracias por recordarme c;